# Crippled nectarine tree leaves

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, nectarines

Not sure what's causing this crippling on the leaves of nectarine leaves. Please help. Zone:9 (northern California)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Peach leaf curl is a common problem: https://www.planetnatural.com/pest-problem-solver/plant-disease/leaf-curl/

[image]

It is a fungal infection and should be treated by spraying your nectarines with fungicide (choose one best suitable for your area and species).